# How to replace .. from string in bash script?

Tags: bash

I have to remove `..` character from a file in Bash script. Example:

I have some string like:

```
some/../path/to/file
some/ab/path/to/file
```

And after replace, it should look like

```
some/path/to/file
some/ab/path/to/file
```

I have used below code

```
DUMMY_STRING=/../
TEMP_FILE=./temp.txt
sed s%${DUMMY_STRING}%/%g ${SRC_FILE} > ${TEMP_FILE}
cp ${TEMP_FILE} ${SRC_FILE}
```

It is replacing the `/../` in line 1; but it is also removing the line `/ab/` from second line. This is not desired. I understand it is considering `/../` as some regex and `/ab/` matches this regex. But I want only those `/../` to be replaced.

Please provide some help.

Thanks,

NN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` is a metacharacter in `sed` meaning 'any character'.  To suppress its special meaning, escape it with a backslash:

```
sed -e 's%/\.\./%/%g' $src_file > $temp_file
```

Note that you are referring to different files after you eliminate the `/../` like that.  To refer to the same name as before (in the absence of symlinks, which complicate things), you would need to remove the directory component before the `/../`.  Thus:

```
some/../path/to/file
path/to/file
```

refer to the same file, assuming `some` is a directory and not a symlink somewhere else, but in general, `some/path/to/file` is a different file (though symlinks could be used to confound that assertion).

---

```
$ x="some/../path/to/file
> some/ab/path/to/file
> /some/path/../to/another/../file"
$ echo "$x"
some/../path/to/file
some/ab/path/to/file
/some/path/../to/another/../file
$ echo "$x" | sed -e 's%/\.\./%/%g'
some/path/to/file
some/ab/path/to/file
/some/path/to/another/file
$ echo "$x" | sed -e "s%/\.\./%/%g"
some/path/to/file
some/ab/path/to/file
/some/path/to/another/file
$ echo "$x" | sed -e s%/\.\./%/%g
some/path/file
some/path/file
/some/path/to/another/file
$ echo "$x" | sed -e s%/\\.\\./%/%g
some/path/to/file
some/ab/path/to/file
/some/path/to/another/file
$
```

Note the careful use of double quotes around the variable `"$x"` in the `echo` commands.  I could have used either single or double quotes in the assignment and would have gotten the same result.

Test on Mac OS X 10.7.4 with the standard `sed` (and shell is `/bin/sh`, aka `bash` 3.2.x), but the results would be the same on any system.

Comment: This is not working as desired. It is also removing "/tx/" which I do not want. I want only that sequence "/../" should be replaced by "/".

Comment: @Niranjan: Are you using single quotes or double quotes around the `sed` script? They are not interchangeable — at least, not in this context. Or are you still not using any quotes? If you do not use single quotes, you have to use more backslashes. As a rule of thumb, enclose `sed` scripts in single quotes unless you need to interpolate a shell variable.

Comment: Got the point Jonathan. I was not using any quote in SED command at all. Your suggestion was proposing to use single quote. That single quote `sed -e 's%/\.\./%/%g' ${SRC_FILE} > ${TEMP_FILE}` solved the problem. Appreciate your help. Thank you very much.